# Google App Engine WordPress wp-admin on custom domain

Tags: wordpress, google-app-engine

Following Google tutorial to setup WordPress on the App Engine I migrated few of my sites there, but Im struggling with one thing. For that reason or another lets say I need to make access to wp-admin backend through custom domain and without SSL support.

No matter what I put in app.yaml

- url: /wp-admin/(.+)
  script: wordpress/wp-admin/\1
  secure: never

for example, it seems that App Engine always redirects to https when attempting to log in to the backend. Has anybody have an idea how can I setup insecure access via http://www.domain.com/wp-admin/ ?

Answer (score 5):

I encountered the similar problem, have no idea if they are same, but you can try my solution.

The real cause of my problem is not from GAE but the **appengine-wordpress-plugin**

1, find the php file "wordpress\wp-content\plugins\google-app-engine\modules\core.php"

2, search string “is_production” and comment out the code below:

```
        if( is_production() ) {
/*      please comment this two statements  
            add_filter( 'secure_auth_redirect', '__return_true' );
            force_ssl_admin( true );
*/    
            other code...
        }
```

3, and don't forget set `secure:never` in app.yaml